# Install old version of phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, homebrew

I want to install an old version of phantomjs (1.9.1). If I run

```
brew install phantomjs
```

It installs the new version (2.0.0).

Answer (score 4):

You can find supported prior versions in the [homebrew-versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions) repository. There isn't a formula for 1.9.1 but you can install 1.9.2 with `brew install homebrew/versions/phantomjs192`. (You could contribute one for 1.9.1 if you really need it.) You can look for versioned formulas with `brew search phantomjs`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this command:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/master/phantomjs182.rb
```

Comment: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/curl --remote-time --location --user-agent Homebrew/1.2.0\ (Macintosh;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.12.4)\ curl/7.51.0 --progress-bar --fail https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/master/phantomjs182.rb -o /Users/petercormack/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/phantomjs182.rb
[~/dragonfly (photo-download)]